# Defining a particular environment in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, environments, indentation

I need help writing an Example environment. I just want it to look like the figure below which I took from an old book I have in my library.

[image]

This is what I have done.

```
    \newtheorem{exem}{EXAMPLE}

    \newenvironment{ex}{\parshape=3
    0\textwidth \textwidth
    0.25\textwidth 0.74\textwidth
    0pt \textwidth \begin{exem} \rm \hspace{0.2cm}}{\end{exem}}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{ex}
        Text
        \end{ex}
    \end{document}
```

However this code fails when the text is very long in the defined environment. Then I start having problems with right margin. I have no idea how to solve it. Please, can you help me to define that environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result would be greatly improved by adding a MWE. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be more disposed to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an `example` environment that sets the paragraph alignment/shape using `\parshape`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcounter{example}
\newcommand{\examplename}{\textsc{Example}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}
  {\refstepcounter{example}% Step example counter
   \sbox\@tempboxa{\examplename~\theexample.~}% Store environment title
   % Set paragraph alignment
   \parshape 3 \wd\@tempboxa \dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\@tempboxa % Line 1
     \wd\@tempboxa \dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\@tempboxa % Line 2
     0pt \linewidth% Line 3+
    \noindent% No indent
    \leavevmode% Start paragraph
    \llap{\usebox\@tempboxa}% Insert environment title
    \ignorespaces}% Remove spaces
  {\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{example}
  Some example content
\end{example}
\begin{example}
  Some more example content
\end{example}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @limber Instead of---or in addition to---posting a “Thank you” as a comment, you should thank Werner by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).